# Cannot convert type 'FlatUI.FlatTextBox' to 'decimal'

Tags: c#, casting

I can't get rid of this error, please help. PS: I'm using the FlatUI theme.

> Cannot convert type 'FlatUI.FlatTextBox' to 'decimal'

[image]

```
xmin1 = Convert.ToDouble(x1.Text);
xmin2 = Convert.ToDouble(x2.Text);
xmin3 = Convert.ToDouble(x3.Text);
xmin4 = Convert.ToDouble(x4.Text);
xmin5 = Convert.ToDouble(x5.Text);
xmin6 = Convert.ToDouble(x6.Text);
xminusanswer = Convert.ToDouble(xAnswer.Text);

xminusans = x1 - (decimal)xAnswer;    // here is where the error happens
```

Comment: You should include your declarations (specifically the declaration of `xAnswer`), not just the small snippet of code that failed.  Also, it's really not a good idea to just link to a remote image like that as your problem description; either embed it, or better yet, include it as text (so it can be searched on).

Comment: As to the actual problem, consider using `decimal.Parse()`; you can't just directly cast a `TextBox` to a `decimal`.

Answer (score 0):

From the error it is clear that `xAnswer` is a `FlatUI.FlatTextBox` and not something that can use explicitly cast to decimal. You need to get the value inside the textbox and then use `Convert.ToDecimal` like:

```
xminusans = x1 - Convert.ToDecimal(xAnswer.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

You converted `Text`s from both `x1` and `xAnswer` to `Double`, but then you use their raw texts for subtraction again. This does not work, because you cannot subtract texts.

Use this instead:

```
xminusans = (decimal)xmin1 - (decimal)xminusanswer;
```

Comment: Error 3 Cannot implicitly convert type 'decimal' to 'double'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) @dasblinkenlight still wont work.